# Scrapy : Create csv file with spider name

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently looking for export scrapped data into files wich name are based on spider name.

Here is my pipelines.py :

```
from mydatacrowd.models import Datacrowd
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter

class CsvExportPipeline(object):

   def _init_(self):
       self.files = {}

   @classmethod
   def from_crawlers(cls, crawler):
       pipeline = cls()
       crawler.signal.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signal.spider_opened)
       crawler.signal.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signal.spider_closed)
       return pipeline

   def spider_opened(self, spider):
       print 'Hello world!'
       print spider.name
       file = open('%s.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')
       self.files[spider] = file
       self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
       self.exporter.start_exporting()

   def spider_closed(self, spider):
       self.exporter.finish_exporting()
       file = self.files.pop(spider)
       file.close()

   def process_item(self, item, spider):

       item.save()
       return item
```

Here is part of my settings.py :

```
...
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
   'datacrowdscrapy.pipelines.CsvExportPipeline': 1000,
}

FEED_FORMAT = 'csv'

FEED_EXPORTERS = {
   'csv': 'datacrowdscrapy.feedexport.CsvScrapperExporter'
}
...
```

And here is my feedexport.py :

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import CsvItemExporter

class CsvScrapperExporter(CsvItemExporter):

   def _init_(self, *args, **kwargs):
       kwargs['fields_to_export'] = settings.getlist('EXPORT_FIELDS') or None
       kwargs['encoding'] = settings.get('EXPORT_ENCODING', 'utf-8')

       super(CsvScrapperExporter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

No file are created, no errors displayed and 'Hello world' never apear in log, what am I missing ?

Thanks !

edit :

No FEED_URI parameter into my settings.py, does that help ?

Comment: You seem to miss a **'** after Hello World.

Comment: Copy / Past error, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looking at scrapy crawl command source it seems that scrapy will only read FEED_EXPORTERS settings if you supply it with an output options like this:

```
scrapy crawl <spider_name> -o csv
```

from scrapy/commands/crawl.py:

```
if opts.output:
    ...
    valid_output_formats = self.settings['FEED_EXPORTERS'].keys() + 
                           self.settings['FEED_EXPORTERS_BASE'].keys()
    ....
    self.settings.overrides['FEED_FORMAT'] = opts.output_format
```

Comment: Did not solve my problem but conturn it doing : scrapy crawl <spider_name> -o <csv_file_name>.csv